# Double Triangle for conclusion

Tags: lists, itemize

[image]

How can I add the double-triangles within a list (itemize)?
Sorry, if this has already been asked but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. Could you show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `enumitem` package and `\blacktriangleright` from `amssymb`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label={$\blacktriangleright$}]
\item first item
\item second item
\item[$\blacktriangleright\blacktriangleright$] third item
\item[$\blacktriangleright\hspace{-0.5ex}\blacktriangleright$] third item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```